# How to count rows calculated by GROUP BY using Criteria Api

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I want to do this by using criteria API:

```
select count(subQ.*)
from (  
    select *
    from items
    group by type
) subQ
```

I need to count types, not elements in each type.
Is it possible ?

Comment: If you want to count types, why don't you just simply use count query on them. How is it related to group by query? Could you pass some example on mock data, what are you aiming at?

Comment: "Count types" is just simple example for brevity. In real life there can be everything in from(...) clause: select ... from ... group by A,B,C ... It depends on user input. I need to show user 25 results per page and TOTAL count.
I dont want to do like this: 
em.createQuery(countCriteria(em, criteria)).getResultList().size(); - it is VERY slow on big data.

Answer (score 0):

Use builder with count method. Here is some working example.

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> cQuery = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<Item> from = cQuery.from(Item.class);
CriteriaQuery<Long> select = cQuery.select(builder.count(from));
```

This is similar to SQL method

```
select count(*) from Item;
```

The same way as you would do with simple query, you can add some predicates to your counting query.

Comment: Hi ! No this is not what i need. You count elements IN groups:
- plane 10
- car 5
- ship 6
I need to count groups(rows) of inner query: 3 rows in abowe example